# How can I combine these two tables in SQL so that each row of the first has a copy of every row in the second?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write an SQL query to combine two tables...

```
Table: names
+-------------+---------------+
|     id      |     Name      |
+-------------+---------------+
|     1       |     Bob       |
|     2       |     Geoff     |
|     3       |     Jim       |
+-------------+---------------+

Table: attributes
+-------------+---------------+
|     id      |   Attribute   |
+-------------+---------------+
|     1       |     Age       |
|     2       |     Height    |
|     3       |     Weight    |
+-------------+---------------+
```

...so that each record in the **names** table has a copy of each record in the Attributes table.

i.e.

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|     id      |     Name      |   Attribute   |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|     1       |     Bob       |     Age       |
|     2       |     Bob       |     Height    |
|     3       |     Bob       |     Weight    |
|     4       |     Geoff     |     Age       |
|     5       |     Geoff     |     Height    |
|     6       |     Geoff     |     Weight    |
|     7       |     Jim       |     Age       |
|     8       |     Jim       |     Height    |
|     9       |     Jim       |     Weight    |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You are describing a `CROSS JOIN`.  See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT n.name, a.attribute from names n cross join attributes a
```

The same can be achieved with following query:

```
SELECT n.name, a.attribute from names n join attributes a ON 1=1
```

The only thing is that you show id from 1 to 9 in the output but there are no such IDs in the sample data. But if you have table with autoincrement then after you insert this data, the ID will be as you expected.

UPDATED:

As suggested in comments and if you need id, then you can do following:

```
SELECT (n.id-1)*3+a.id AS id, n.name, a.attribute from names n cross join attributes a
```

Comment: One *could* calculate the resultant `id` column (in this case) as `n.id*3+a.id`—but I can't imagine one would ever want to do that in practice.

Comment: Actually not. for the first record it will be 1*3+1 = 4

Comment: In MySQL the `ON 1=1` is not needed.

Comment: @sidux: Fair enough—`(n.id-1)*3+a.id` then.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an incremented id, just use a variable:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, n.name, a.attribute
from names n cross join
     attributes a cross join
     (select @rn := 0) vars;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select stu.id,stu.name,attribute.attribute from stu cross join 
attribute order by stu.id
```